# How do I take a column of data and put it into a custom size (mxn) matrix using MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, matrix

I have a a column of 71,337 data points and want to put the data in the form of a 237x301 matrix. The column of data points is already in order, so the first 301 points would be placed in the first row of the matrix, then the next 301 points in the next row and so forth...

Can I do this with Matlab? If so how EXACTLY? Thanks!

Comment: Think `reshape(data,301,237).'` might work.

Comment: @user3145111: you might want to know that MATLAB uses [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Matlab's `reshape` function

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

Comment: Thanks this worked! I had to use reshape then transpose to get exactly what I wanted.